# Linq statement distinct not working on dates

Tags: c#, linq

I've been looking all over stackoverflow.com and the Interwebz to find out how to use Linq with `Distinct()`, but I'm not having any luck with my situation.

What I'm trying to do is show a list of dates (Aug 2015, July 2015, etc) with each date showing just once.

What happens is that the months are duplicated because you can publish a new blog post more than once in a month. I thought using Distinct would help, but it seems like it's not doing anything. When I try adding `GroupBy()`, my `OrderByDescending` stops working, and I'm not seasoned enough to simply turn this into an `IList`, which I've seen in a couple other examples.

```
BlogRepeater.DataSource = _PostRepository.GetAll(ConfigurationManager.GetSiteID())
    .Where(x => x.DatePublished != null && x.DatePublished >= DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1))
    .Distinct().OrderByDescending(x => x.DatePublished)
    .Select(x => x.DatePublished.Value.Date);
```

What is the best way to be doing this?

I've tried taking pieces from other examples, to no avail. Thanks in advance.

[image]

UPDATE: Thanks for the help! Here is working code in hopes it can help someone else in the future.

Code Behind:

```
BlogRepeater.DataSource = 
            _PostRepository
            .GetAll(ConfigurationManager.GetSiteID())
            .Where(x => x.DatePublished != null && x.DatePublished >= DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1) && x.Status == "Published")
            .Select(x => x.DatePublished.Value.ToString("MMM yyyy"))
            .Distinct()
            .OrderBy(x => x);
        BlogRepeater.DataBind();
```

Front End:

```
<a href="/Blog/Archive/<%#(Container.DataItem)%>"><%#(Container.DataItem)%></a>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your `DatePublished` field contains DateTime values with different times, the `.Distinct()` will not behave how you expect it to, because those values are essentially different.

If you want distinct dates, not date/times, then you can move the last `.Select` before the `.Distinct()`:

```
BlogRepeater.DataSource = 
  _PostRepository
    .GetAll(ConfigurationManager.GetSiteID())
    .Where(x => x.DatePublished != null && x.DatePublished >= DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1))
    .Select(x => x.DatePublished.Value.Date)   
    .Distinct()
    .OrderByDescending(x => x);
```

---

If you want to find the distinct months, not dates, then you have to change the

```
.Select(x => x.DatePublished.Value.Date)
```

line to

```
.Select(x => x.DatePublished.Value.ToString("MMM yyyy"))
```

Feel free to change the `"MMM yyyy"` format to anything else you find suitable.

Comment: Seems simple enough, but when I do that, the code forgets what DatePublished is. 'System.DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'DatePublished' and no extension method 'DatePublished' accepting a first argument of type 'System.DateTime' could be found. It's only letting me use OrderByDescending as one of the first parts of the query.

Comment: @jlg Yes, sorry, I forgot to update the `OrderByDescending` clause accordingly. See the update to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! The query was able to run, but the `Distinct()` is still not working. Check the image I added to the post.

Comment: @jlg the `.Select(x => x.DatePublished.Value.Date)` should take care of that. If it still does not work, try posting some data from your `_PostRepository`.

Comment: @jlg OK, so apparently you want a list of months, not dates. See the latest update to my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help! I've been racking my brain off and on for a week now and some other guys at work weren't able to get this either. :D

Comment: @jlg I'm glad it helped!